# Find and click element by... Python Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to click an element. In inspect element i can see this:

```
<a href="/sondc.phtml"><b>S</b>ondeos por territorios</a>
```

And this is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://www.ogimet.com/")

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read());

#print(bsObj)

nameList = bsObj.findAll("a")
```

I don't know what does it mean href. I don't know if that is an atributte. Can you help me?

Comment: You don't even use selenium in your code (yet). And with BeautifulSoup you can't click anything. `href` is the link location: It's the place you land at when you click the link

Answer (score 1):

If you want to click the "Sondeos por territorios" link with selenium, this will do it.

```
from selenium import webdriver

#this path may be different on your cpu, you need to install a browser driver
driver_loc = r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe' 
url = 'http://www.ogimet.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_loc) 
driver.get(url)

the_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[19]/a')
the_link.click()
```